# How do you add rows retrieved from database to an arraylist (of objects?) in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

```
    selectStatement = 'SELECT * FROM table'

    try {
        // The eachRow method is an Iterator
           sql.eachRow( selectStatement ) {

        //Need to add results to an arraylist row by row. Each object in the
        //arraylist must contain : Id, Description, Code, isDefault. I  have
        //access to those values by calling ${it.SKILL_ID}, ${it.DESCRIPTION},
        //${it.SKILL_CODE}, ${it.IS_DEFAULT}. id is int, description and code are
        //strings and is default is a bit

        }
    } catch (e) {

    }
```

Also if you can help me by iterating over the elements of the arraylist until i match the Code.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wouldn't [`rows`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#rows%28groovy.lang.GString%29) give you basically what you want?

> Now try a query using rows:
>
> ```
> def rows = sql.rows("select * from PROJECT where name like 'Gra%'")
> assert rows.size() == 2
> println rows.join('\n')
> ```
>
> with output like this:
>
> ```
> [ID:20, NAME:Grails, URL:http://grails.org]
> [ID:40, NAME:Gradle, URL:http://gradle.org]
> ```

Comment: I need to fetch everything from the db first then save it in an arraylist. I dont want to query the db for every comparison i need to make...

Comment: @SMelikian i don't understand what you mean by "fetch everything from db"?  your code above does a `select * from table`, which would obviously go in the quote above, where the `select * from project...` is. Could you please be more specific what the ultimate goal here is? `rows` returns a `List<GroovyRowResult>`.

Comment: The table in my database has 4 columns and maybe 100 rows. I want to fetch all the rows and store each row as an object in an arraylist. So the arraylist will contain all the information from my table as objects that contain 4 variables each SKILL_ID, DESCRIPTION, SKILL_CODE, IS_DEFAULT.

Comment: Ok thank you. Btw who is downvoting the question ? It's not a school assignment or anything... it's not that obvious for people who aren't programming experts nor is it that obvious when you start coding in a new programming language...